# Stripe Checkout webhook - which event to listen for

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks

**Background:**

I've implemented [Stripe Checkout](https://stripe.com/payments/checkout) in a React app, and a [webhook](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/test) that successfully listens to events.

These are the events that the webhook hears after a successful Checkout:

```
checkout.session.completed
charge.succeeded
payment_method.attached
customer.created
customer.updated
invoice.created
invoice.finalized
customer.subscription.created
invoice.updated
customer.subscription.updated
invoice.paid
invoice.payment_succeeded
payment_intent.succeeded
payment_intent.created
```

---

**What I'm trying to do:**

I need to save a value to the database after a customer successfully creates a subscription. This value helps enable paid features, so I have to be sure the webhook catches all successful events.

---

**Question:**

Can I consistently rely on only one of these webhook events to indicate success? If not, which ones are the most important to listen for?

I think the most important events for my use case are probably `checkout.session.completed`, `charge.succeeded`, and `payment_intent.succeeded`, but I'm not too sure on how these are different and if/when some of them may not appear.

The [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/migration/charges#understanding-the-stripe-payment-apis) indicate:

> There are three ways to accept payments on Stripe today:
>
> - Stripe Checkout
> - Charges API
> - Payment Intents API

[and](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types):

> - `checkout.session.completed`: Occurs when a Checkout Session has been successfully completed.
> - `charge.succeeded`: Occurs whenever a charge is successful.
> - `payment_intent.succeeded`: Occurs when a PaymentIntent has successfully completed payment.

So my guess is that each of `checkout.session.completed`, `charge.succeeded`, and `payment_intent.succeeded` indicate success, and the reason all three are returned is that they correspond to the three ways to currently accept payments on Stripe.

If this is the case, can I reliably listen for only `checkout.session.completed` to indicate success?

---

**Other info:**

`stripe listen --forward-to localhost:4242/myWebHook` output after a successful Checkout session:

(actual `evt_` values replaced for simplicity)

```
2022-05-08   --> checkout.session.completed [evt_123456]
2022-05-08   --> charge.succeeded [evt_123456]
2022-05-08   --> payment_method.attached [evt_123456]
2022-05-08   --> customer.created [evt_123456]
2022-05-08   --> customer.updated [evt_123456]
2022-05-08   --> invoice.created [evt_123456]
2022-05-08   --> invoice.finalized [evt_123456]
2022-05-08   --> customer.subscription.created [evt_123456]
2022-05-08   --> invoice.updated [evt_123456]
2022-05-08   --> customer.subscription.updated [evt_123456]
2022-05-08   --> invoice.paid [evt_123456]
2022-05-08   <--  [200] POST http://localhost:4242/myWebHook [evt_123456]
2022-05-08   <--  [200] POST http://localhost:4242/myWebHook  [evt_123456]
2022-05-08   <--  [200] POST http://localhost:4242/myWebHook  [evt_123456]
2022-05-08   <--  [200] POST http://localhost:4242/myWebHook  [evt_123456]
2022-05-08   <--  [200] POST http://localhost:4242/myWebHook  [evt_123456]
2022-05-08   <--  [200] POST http://localhost:4242/myWebHook  [evt_123456]
2022-05-08   --> invoice.payment_succeeded [evt_123456]
2022-05-08   <--  [200] POST http://localhost:4242/myWebHook  [evt_123456]
2022-05-08   <--  [200] POST http://localhost:4242/myWebHook  [evt_123456]
2022-05-08   <--  [200] POST http://localhost:4242/myWebHook  [evt_123456]
2022-05-08   <--  [200] POST http://localhost:4242/myWebHook  [evt_123456]
2022-05-08   <--  [200] POST http://localhost:4242/myWebHook  [evt_123456]
2022-05-08   <--  [200] POST http://localhost:4242/myWebHook  [evt_123456]
2022-05-08   --> payment_intent.succeeded [evt_123456]
2022-05-08   <--  [200] POST http://localhost:3000/myWebHook  [evt_123456]
2022-05-08   --> payment_intent.created [evt_123456]
2022-05-08   <--  [200] POST http://localhost:3000/myWebHook  [evt_123456]
```

Comment: Don't forget that you can store metadata in several major Stripe objects that can be picked up later by the webhook handler.  The best general approach to a Stripe webhook is to store incoming events in a database with a primary key of event ID and mark new entries as "unprocessed."  Then a script runs periodically that handles the unprocessed entries in creation timestamp order.  You'll need such a script to correctly process subscription renewals.  Note that webhooks are not guaranteed to arrive (e.g. technical problems like an expired TLS certificate) nor arrive in order.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The events which most users usually listen for successful subscription creation are :

- `checkout.session.completed`, or
- `invoice.paid` and check the `billing_reason` to determine why the invoice was created : https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object#invoice_object-billing_reason

There's no single correct answer because which event you would want to listen for would depend on a variety of factors e.g.

- if the event you're listening for contains the information you need
- for `checkout.session.completed`, if you're only taking in card payments (no async payment methods), then yes, you can rely on `checkout.session.completed` to save a value to the database after a customer successfully creates a subscription. However, if you do accept async payment methods as well, you would want to listen for and handle additional events listed here : https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders#delayed-notification
- Some users want to save all paid invoices (including those for subscription renewals) to their database. In which case, it may make more sense to listen for the `invoice.paid` event.

There are reasons to not use `charge.succeeded` or `payment_intent.succeeded` :

- If the invoice amount = 0, e.g. trials, there will be no PaymentIntent / Charge created.
- If you mark the invoice as paid out of band, then the PaymentIntent would be cancelled and you would never receive these two events.

I'd suggest reading through https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/overview for a better understanding of how subscriptions work.